# NSRegularExpression pattern for mobile no validation

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, mobile

Please someone help me to make pattern for mobile number validation using NSRegularExpression  in ObejctiveC.
Here is the rule:

```
  1. Number should start with 01 
  2. 3rd digit between 5 and 9
  3. Total length should be 11
```

Comment: You can use regex to validate it

Comment: @mkowal87 can you please provide a sample, since I am new to this, that will be easy for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to perform validation would be to use a Regex. There is a wrapper in iOS called `NSRegularExpression`. Unfortunately, I can't give you some 'magic bullet' code as your Regex will likely need to be different to mine. (Given that mine is looking for a UK mobile number, yours might not be).

This code validates a string against the **United Kingdom mobile number** standard.

```
NSString *str = @"07578565203"
NSError *err;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(07\d{8,9})$" options:nil error:&err];
NSTextCheckingResult *result [regex firstMatchInString:str options:nil range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
if (result == 1) {
    // number is valid
} else {
    // number is invalid, check err to see why
}
```

Note the `initWithPattern` of the `NSRegularExpression`. You must pass the pattern that works for your phone number. You can generate one [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220828085106/https://regexr.com/). This site is also good for teaching you about RegEx.

If you get stuck, let me know the rules of a phone number where you live and I will write a Regex.

**EDIT:** A suitable RegEx for Bangladesh, as per OP's comment, would be `(01[5-9]\d{8})$`.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob King for sharing the code. If you can share the regular expression based on my rule, it will be really helpful
Here is my rule:
1. Number should start with 01 
  2. 3rd digit between 5 and 9
  3. Total length should be 11
This is the mobile number format iin Bangladesh

Comment: See edit for Bangladesh regex.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob King, it was really helpful.
Here is what I tried
NSError *errRegex = NULL;
                    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(01[5-9]\\d{8})$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&errRegex];
                    
                    NSUInteger countMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:mobileNo options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [mobileNo length])];